# Found an error in ggsurvplot with unused argument

Tags: r

I don't understand the error I get when running the following code:

```
library("survminer")
require("survival")
fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung)
```

It says :
"Error in ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung) : unused argument (data = lung)"

What does it mean ? We must specify data, don't we ?

Comment: Look at `sessionInfo()` to see what version of `survimer` and `survival` you are using. I could not reproduce this error with `survminer_0.4.3` and `survival_2.41-3`. According to the `ggsurvplot` help file I see, the `data=` is not required because it can use the same source as the model you pass in.

Comment: 'sessionInfo()' gives : 'survminer_0.4.3' and 'survival_2.40-1' ; do I have to update the 'survival' package ?

Comment: So you can just leave the `data=` part off. Again, it's not necessary. That information is already in the `fit` object.

Comment: I updated survival to version survival_2.42-3 and removed data=...

Comment: Now a new strange error : Error in grDevices::col2rgb(colour, TRUE) : 
  numerical color values must be positive

Comment: You get that by copying and pasting the code above in a new R session?